# Login Id being used though the id has been deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a web-site(used for internal purpose) in our office. The issue that i am facing is we have deleted the login for a user and recreated a new login ID. But the previous Login ID is being reflected i.e the old login ID is still intact with the account. We have even checked the DB and the login status reflected is deleted.

Please let me know in-case if you require more details.

Thanks in advance for all the help provided.

Cheers,
Nitesh

Comment: When you say deleted, do you mean actually deleted, or marked as "deleted" by a variable in the table? Also, if you clear your cookies, are you still logged in as the "deleted" user?

Comment: It is being marked 'Y' in the Deleted column in the Login table.

Comment: How about the cookies? And are you storing the logged-in user in session by any chance where the app might think they are still logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Please check on verify user code there deleted user validation is or not. if not then add condition deleted user would be false.

Comment: Hi Amit, I did not understand what you said.

Comment: @Nitesh when you are requesting to validate username and password, at there add condition for deleted user would be false, if you are marking deleted user is true while deleting the user.

Answer (score 0):

When you say its being reflected,
Does it allow the old user account to be authenticated still?

If the DB is updated then this should not happen. Does your application generate a cookie for the user? If so, try deleting the browser cookies.

Comment: I am not sure if the browser is generating a cookie for the user. Will check it and update you.

Comment: Check the event handler for the login forms "Login button" in the code behind.

You may just have a cookie stored in your browser from the previous user.